# how to integrate a function like this: $\int_0^x \frac{(t)^{a-1}}{(x-t)^a} dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have tried to do it myself and then looked for any hint here, but I can't reach the solution. Is it possible that it simplifies to a sine function when integrated between the limits 0 and x.
$$\int_0^x\frac{(t)^{a-1}}{(x-t)^a} dt$$
where $0<a<1$

Answer (score 4):

Let $x>0$. An obvious substitition gives
$$\int_0^x\frac{t^{a-1}}{(x-t)^a}\, dt=\int_0^1 u^{a-1}(1-u)^{-a}\,du.$$
This is a beta integral and equals
$$B(a,1-a)=\frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(1-a)}{\Gamma(1)}=\frac\pi{\sin\pi a}.$$